# Sorting Arrays ascending?

Tags: c#, sorting

I have a list of films that I have input into the console using streamreader, I want to sort these ascendingly, but I can't seem to figure out how, can anyone help? Thanks

Code so far:

```
//Program that has popular film names on an external datafile, which then reads the files and
//displays them in the console window

//Declare variables
int iOneWordTitle;

//Declare array
const int iFilm = 7;
string[] sOneWordTitle = new string[iFilm];

//Add title to console
Console.WriteLine("List of one word film titles");
Console.WriteLine();

//Read the film names from the datafile
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filmnames.txt"))
{
    for (iOneWordTitle = 0; iOneWordTitle < iFilm; iOneWordTitle++)
    {
        sOneWordTitle[iOneWordTitle] = (sr.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine(sOneWordTitle[iOneWordTitle]);
    }

    Array.Sort(sOneWordTitle); //Sort ascending
}

//Prevent program from closing
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: I usually ask for the code so far, but in this particular case, I must say that almost the whole code is pretty much irrelevant to the question.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the problem exactly? As an aside, you are using a variant of Hungarian notation that prefixes variables with their type. Many people (myself included) consider this practice bad because it just adds noise. The compiler will not let you mix incompatible types anyway.

Comment: What is your Problem? Array.Sort(sOneWordTitle); should already sort the array corectly.

Comment: You can simplify a bit to `var sOneWordTitle = File.ReadAllLines("filmnames.txt"); Array.Sort(sOneWordTitle);`. That will read all lines, not just seven. If you want only seven, maybe use `var sOneWordTitle = File.ReadLines("filmnames.txt").Take(iFilm).ToList(); sOneWordTitle.Sort();`. It is not a good practice in C# to declare all local variables at the top. For example, the loop variable for a `for` loop should be declared near/in the `for` loop itself.

Answer (score 4):

you are sorting it correctly.
The problem is that you are displaying the records as you read them and before sorting.
You need an additional loop to display your elements AFTER `Array.Sort`

Comment: thanks for the reply, Ah okay.. Any suggestions how I'd do this? I'm pretty nooby with C#, thanks

Comment: @user2985995: just copy your `for` loop, paste it under `Array.Sort` and in your second loop remove the line `sOneWordTitle[iOneWordTitle] = (sr.ReadLine());`

Answer (score 2):

You can do it all in 'one line':

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("filmnames.txt"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, sr.ReadToEnd().Split(new []{'\r', '\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).OrderBy(p => p)));
}
```

What does this do?

1. The most nested method is a call to `ReadToEnd`. This reads the entrie file to a single string.
2. The call to `string.Split` splits the string into an array of strings where new lines occur.
3. The call to LINQ's `OrderBy` method does the actual sort using the raw `string` of each file name
4. `string.Join` reassembles the names into one `string` using newlines as seperators (so that you get each film on its own line)
5. `Console.WriteLine` does what you would expect ;)

A little complicated for a *new guy*™ but there are some interesting things going on. `string.Join` is worth knowing about.

Here it is without the using statement, just for giggles.

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, File.ReadAllLines("filmnames.txt").OrderBy(p => p)));
```

Comment: @F.R.I.E.N.D.S. fistbump!

Comment: Just use static method `File.ReadLines("filmnames.txt")`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen OP stated that a `StreamReader` is used so i retained it. `StreamReader` can read from many sources, not just files.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go ahead and guess that C# isn't your mother tongue :)

The usuall (prettier) way to implement this would be something like:

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>();

using (var sr = new StreamReader("filmnames.txt"))
{
  string line;

  while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    lines.Add(line);
  }
}

lines.Sort();

// Or...

lines = lines.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();

// And write the output
foreach (var line in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(line);
```

Comment: The call to `ToList` is not needed. `foreach` will operate upon an IEnumerable<T> without issue.

Comment: Just do `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines("filmnames.txt").OrderBy(x => x)) Console.WriteLine(line);`.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen: Yeah, that's a nice way. I wanted to make it seem less like magic :)